# Does deleting venv delete installed modules?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Does deleting a python virtual environment (venv) directory delete the modules installed in it?

I see the installed modules both in the venv directory and also under Python3.7/Scripts directory. I can access the installed modules even when I am outside the venv. If I delete the venv directory will I not be able to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you delete the venv directory the modules installed in it are deleted.

Where as you have those modules in your Python3.7/Scripts directory also.

So, you can access them even if you delete venv directory.